# Swift regex for checking if string has at least one uppercase letter

Tags: regex, swift, uppercase

I have tried several things like:

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])
^(?=.*?[A-Z])$
^(.*?[A-Z])$
```

nothing works

```
static func atLeastOneUpperCase(_ input: String) -> Bool {
    return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", upperCaseRegex).evaluate(with: input)
}
```

The input should be one of the above.

Comment: Give some sample positive and negative matches

Comment: I don't see a reason why the first regex wouldn't work. Are you sure you're using it correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Swift, when you use `NSPredicate` with `MATCHES`, you *require a full string match*.

So, in your case, you need to use

```
let upperCaseRegex = "(?s)[^A-Z]*[A-Z].*"
```

This will match a whole string that starts with 0+ chars other than uppercase ASCII letters, then will match 1 ASCII letter, and then will match any 0+ chars (since `(?s)` allows a dot to match any char including line break characters).

Another way is to use [`range(of:options:range:locale:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1642786-range), passing the `.regularExpression` option:

```
return input.range(of: "[A-Z]", options: .regularExpression) != nil
```

This will allow matching a regex in an unanchored way, i.e. this way, the regex engine will be looking for a *partial* match, and won't require the full string match any longer.

**Unicode considerations**

If you need to check for *any* Unicode uppercase letter, use `\p{Lu}` instead of `[A-Z]`:

```
return input.range(of: "\\p{Lu}", options: .regularExpression) != nil
```

Or, if you need to use `NSPredicate` version:

```
let upperCaseRegex = "(?s)\\P{Lu}*\\p{Lu}.*"
```

Note that here, `\P{Lu}*` matches 0+ chars other than uppercase letters.

Comment: eventually I used : "^(.*[A-Z]+.*"

Comment: @user3239711: In the NSPredicate, you may use `.*[A-Z].*`. But it is less efficient than `[^A-Z]*[A-Z].*`. Well, if you are sure the strings have no line breaks and that they are short, `.*[A-Z].*` is OK.

Answer (score 4):

If you aren't checking for any particular position of the capital letter then `[A-Z]` will work. For example in javascript I would use `/[A-Z]/.test("fRed")` and get true and `/[A-Z]/.test("fred")` returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
[A-Z]+
```

- `[A-Z]`: a single character in the range between A (ASCII 65) and Z
         (ASCII 90) (case sensitive).
- `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many
  times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy).

See it working in the <kbd>[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/JeR243/1)</kbd>.

Comment: Note that in Javascript, this is an infinite regex. So I wouldn't really use it.

Comment: But the question isn't tagged as JS, however I am interested @KarlReid to improve my answer. What would you suggest?

Comment: To be honest I would just use `[A-Z]+`!  If all that's needed is to test if there are capital letters, it seems like it would be fine. I should clarify that there's nothing really wrong with your regex, it just needs a bit of care. If you use it with the `g` flag in Javascript and call `exec` repeatedly, it's an infinite loop, AFAIU

Comment: Thank you @KarlReid, I updated my answer, how does it look now to you?

Comment: It's fine, but you don't need to change it completely because of a comment I made, I'm not an expert and I could be completely wrong.. post an answer that you yourself are confident in :)

Comment: @KarlReid well I didn't do that because you told me, but because you suggested it and I thougt about it! ;)

Comment: Well, it is not working. Your syntax works when all the charaters  are uppuer case. Just to give some precision, I am developing in swift :

Comment: @user3239711 I don't know swift. I answered in general, since your question didn't specify swift. See the live demo, which proves that it works fine in general, for example with "ssasaFsasaas".